# Add jar to JupyterHub when running Spark with Scala

Tags: apache-spark, jupyter, amazon-emr

When running Spark on JupyterHub on EMR I would like to add some connector Jar.
I use Scala and seems klike there is no way to import classes from custom Jar.

Is someone know a way to do so?
Thanks

Comment: Would running your jar and getting its output would do what you want or do you want to import some classes from it?

Comment: use its classes, In specific example connect to Cassandra cluster using a connector, that should be imported

Comment: Maybe the option `spark.driver.extraClassPath` option is what you are looking for. I found the following command `spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", classpath).getOrCreate()`. Can't try it for now thought, I'll test it later if needed. Please note that the `classpath` must be on aws s3, so something like `s3://myBucket/path/to/jar`.